# Cache modification notification?

Tags: java, guava

I'm looking for something similar to RemovalListener/RemovalNotification - but notification of when values in the cache are modified.  Notification would include the old value, as well as the new value that has just been added.

[update]
I only populate the cache via a CaceLoader (load & reload).  The "source" of the cached elements are at times flakey (remote to the cache).
So the two primary reason for having the replacement element as well are:

1. Debug logging to indicate when/what values are actually retrieved
   from the remote source.  This one could be accomplished in a class
   that does the remote retrieval.
2. Generate difference that can then be proactively pushed to (remote)
   clients.  e.g. publishing changes via blazeDS, rather than requiring
   the clients to continuously "get".

It should be possible to implement this without additional notification via the reload method, and getting the current cache contents before going off and getting the new value, and then comparing the new value and the previous value - and then taking additional action.  I was looking for a more generic way to decouple the modification notification.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you interacting with your cache?  Is it just via `put`, or via `refresh`, or what?

Answer (score 1):

You could file a Guava feature request asking for a method to be added to RemovalNotification that would return the replacement value when the cause is REPLACED. But please provide as much detail as possible about your problem and why this is a good solution for it.